# How to add library to PKG-CONFIG Mac

Tags: c, flickr, pkg-config

I am trying to get flikcurl to sync with pkg-config. I tried installing it via macports, but it results in an error during build.

I am able to find the flickurl.a static library and the src headers.

My question is, how do I add these to the PKG_CONFIG path?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you find a .pc file?

Comment: Yep, I can find a flickcurl.pc file. What would I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

If flickcurl.pc is in the directory /p/a/t/h, you need to add /p/a/t/h to PKG_CONFIG_PATH, which is a colon separated list of all the places that pkg-config will look for pc files:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:}/p/a/t/h
```

Comment: I did this: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:}~/Projects/flickcurl-1.22/

and I get: 

Package flickcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `flickcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'flickcurl' found

Any tips? What I did wrong?

Comment: Try replacing '~' with $HOME.

Comment: Try the simpler: PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/Projects/flickcurl-1.22  If ~/Projects/flickcurl-1.22/flickcurl.pc exists, that should work.

Comment: Interesting: on my box (RedHat) using ~ works, but often ~ gets expanded in odd ways and it is generally a good idea to use $HOME.

Comment: Any tips on getting the same thing done with ffmpeg that have .a files?

Comment: If the library does not supply a .pc file, you can always write your own.  Use flickcurl.pc as a template.